# Javascript adds spaces and extra letters

Tags: javascript

I need help for a Javascript that shortens the text based on the number of characters. The problem is when the full paragraph is displayed, the script adds a space to the word and repeats the last character.

[image: 1] The image above is the shortened paragraph. When I click on "MEHR", it expands but also adds a space and the last character of the word (in this case the word is "Berücksichtigung" but is displayed as "Berück ksichtigung").

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showChar = 400;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Mehr";
    var lesstext = "Weniger";
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();

        if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></span>';

            $(this).html(html);
        }

    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

And the working code can be found here: https://www.impct.help

I look forward to your solution :)

Comment: `&nbsp;` is the space. You could remove `&nbsp;`  before `<span class="morecontent">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra `&nbsp;` (non breaking-space element). Also, the extra character is repeated because on the `-1` in the computation of `h`. Here a correct solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var showChar = 400;
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Mehr";
    var lesstext = "Weniger";
    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();

        if(content.length > showChar) {

            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);

            var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses" style="display:none">'+ellipsestext+'</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink less">'+moretext+'</a></span>';

            $(this).html(html);
        }

    });

    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="more">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras consectetur ligula id odio malesuada, id ornare nunc malesuada. Sed mollis urna vel dictum blandit. Phasellus eu ultrices dolor. Morbi a urna eget nisl viverra sodales. Integer ac arcu justo. Pellentesque ullamcorper diam justo, id placerat justo interdum sit amet. Nunc cursus, ipsum quis aliquet ultrices, urna lorem posuere turpis, at pharetra magna nisi ac felis. Vivamus eu dui tristique, congue orci et, sagittis ipsum. Pellentesque varius augue sit amet nulla commodo pellentesque. Vivamus malesuada gravida iaculis. Fusce sollicitudin velit ut neque aliquet, sed tincidunt erat volutpat.

Nulla facilisi. Cras blandit neque non mauris tincidunt consequat. Pellentesque in tellus sit amet erat sodales sagittis eu efficitur enim. Morbi dapibus mattis ex, eu faucibus ante aliquet sit amet. Vivamus tristique, massa id efficitur placerat, dui nisl gravida eros, sed accumsan mauris eros quis tortor. Nam tortor velit, sodales ac nisl ut, dapibus eleifend orci. Maecenas commodo fringilla faucibus. Nunc et lorem pretium, elementum orci non, sollicitudin felis. Cras at dolor facilisis, interdum est vel, malesuada est. Morbi tincidunt laoreet leo nec interdum. Praesent vitae pharetra libero, quis finibus magna.

</div>
```

Comment: Roland that did the trick and @Greedo, thanks for spotting the -1 and the complete script :)